# Removing default (auto-detect) Tasks (launch.json and task.json) in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, task

When I try to **Run Build Task** for any C/C++ file, I am asked by VScode to determine which task I want to use, or configure a new **task.json**, via a pop-up menu. As shown in the screenshot in the below
[image]

Now there are just too many tasks, I want to remove some of them so that the recent ones that I configured will be shown in the menu.

So, I am looking for a way to delete those ones and have my recently configured tasks as the defaults.

I am on macOS Catalina, using the latest version of VScode.

Comment: open `.vscode/tasks.json` and delete the tasks you don't want

Comment: @rioV8
you are talking about the .vscode directory in the current project? or in the macOS home directory? 
if it is regarding the current opened folder/workspace then that won't work because the recommendations are popping-up for every new project, whether its empty, or it has a task.json

Comment: project folder `.vscode`. There is no `tasks.json` in the home directory. The detected tasks are from the C++ extensions, set one of the tasks in `tasks.json` as the default build task

Comment: @rioV8 I know it is coming from the C/C++ extension, but I just want to get rid of them
can't I? 
also, how do I set one to be the default? right now, I am using "group" { isDefault: "true" } 
but that is just requiring reconfiguring every time.
If you know any links to have a one-time setup on macOS I would be grateful.

Comment: also mention it is the `build` group, look at the Tasks doc

Answer (score 1):

Set  task.autoDetect  to off

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_task-autodetection

It can also be overridden per extension

```
{
  "typescript.tsc.autoDetect": "off",
  "grunt.autoDetect": "off",
  "jake.autoDetect": "off",
  "gulp.autoDetect": "off",
  "npm.autoDetect": "off"
}
```

like so if the extension supports it.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to remove selected tasks from the recent tasks list will be in v1.52.

> #### Remove recent tasks
>
> The tasks quickpick has always had a "Recent Tasks" section at the
> top. Since this is a valuable place, you can now better curate your
> recent tasks by removing them from that section.

from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_52.md#remove-recent-tasks